# Keep jQuery collapsible menu bar expanded

Tags: php, jquery, navigationbar

Menu collapses when link is clicked because it loads a new page. Is there anyway I can keep the menu expanded using php variable?

```
<ul class="<? echo $page_id; ?>">

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

 $('.page_id').slideDown(); // this is where I would like to use variable!

 $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
    $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for teaching!

Comment: What part of the code is unclear? On click, if the class isn't "active" it does slideUp, slideToggle(), removes active class from the sibling A element and adds active class to clicked element. That makes it expanded. Which implies if you use that for a specific item upon page load and not on click...

Comment: The codes works well for navigation. However, once I click the sub menu which leads me to a new page, the side bar collapse by default. I need to keep the sub menu expanded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on page load open it:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  //slide down on page load
  $('#nav li ul').slideDown();

 $('#nav > li > a').click(function(){
  if ($(this).attr('class') != 'active'){
    $('#nav li ul').slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $('#nav li a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I have a page id $pageid. How can I replace the selector: $('#nav li ul').slideDown();? Many Thanks

Comment: $('#<?=$pageid;?>').slideDown(); ?

Comment: Yes! Thanks! It's very helpful. Now it works exactly the way I want!